# How to read dictionary definitions in Collins Gem German/English dictionary

Tags: dictionary, reference

I'm at beginner German and I'm learning to use a translation dictionary properly. I'm currently using the Collins Gem German Dictionary, small size, and it has the format:

`Headword (Genitive, Plural) Gender Meaning`

`Golf (-(e)s, -e) m gulf; der ~ von Biskaya the Bay of Biskay ▷ (-s) nt golf; ...`

I've a few questions about this:

1. There is no IPA pronunciation for German words, but there is for every English word in the other half of the dictionary. At first this concerned me but I'm guessing English needs IPA but German maybe doesn't? This is disconcerting for someone accustomed to IPA so maybe I need to look for a dictionary with German IPA? Or maybe I'll do fine using the rules of German pronunciation?
2. When the genitive is listed as -(e)s this implies the genitive can be formed as either -es or -s, but why is there a choice?

Wikipedia says: "Singular masculine and neuter nouns of the strong declension in the genitive case are marked with -(e)s. Generally, one-syllable nouns favour the -es ending, and it is obligatory with nouns ending with a sibilant such as s or z. Otherwise, a simple -s ending is usual."

And that's fine when speaking in general but surely for any specific given word the choice should be indicated by the dictionary?

3. A tilde (~) is being used as a shorthand for repetition of the headword? der ~ von Biskaya === der Golf von Biskaya?
4. the right arrow ▷ indicates a second defined meaning of the same headword? Why not just a semicolon (;)?
5. In the second part of the definition it lists (-s) where I would expect to see (Genitive, Plural), so is it the genitive or the plural? Is it possible I'm expected to know that english golf has no plural, so it's just the genitive?

Is there a reference that explains this?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your question is not about German language and therefore off-topic. A reference should be in the dictionary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about German language.

Comment: Is there any advantage nowadays to using a paper dictionary over one of the excellent on-line dictionaries available? In any case, I recommend being familiar with multiple dictionaries since they tend to have their own strengths and specializations.

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot of questions - and some of them are the choice of the editors to which we could only speculate and which you will have to address to the editor themselves or you should find the answer within the book itself.

ad 2) There are cases where a word can have several ways to form a case. This is fairly often the case for the Genitive with -es or -s. For some words, like "Golf" one can equally rightfully say "An der Küste des Golfes finden sich schöne Strände" as "An der Küste des Golfs finden sich schöne Strände". Tendentially the form with "-es" is the older form, as with just "-s" is shorter, but it's far from out-of-use.

ad 5) If there is a plural, there is also a genitive form; this if there is only one I expect it to be Genitive form. But here also the book should explain its notation somewhere.

Mind that Collins has both, a German-English dictionary and an English-German dictionary. In each only the IPA of one language is given, assuming that you are a proficient speaker of the other language.

Comment: In German, unlike English, the pronunciation of a word is almost always predictable from the spelling. I think that's why the IPA isn't given for German entries. But you do have to know German's pronunciation rules which can be hard to get used to for a learner. (E.g. "Feuer" is _not_ pronounced like "fewer".)

Comment: Yesish. But the rules only apply to native German words - but I'd recon there's many loan words to which it makes sense to give a pronunciation: "Im Atelier habe ich das Handy in die Sauce fallen lassen, weil der Baby-Song im Radio kam"

Comment: Good point. I suppose you could give IPA just for foreign words. I'm used to dictionaries where there's a voice actually saying the word, bypassing the whole IPA issue altogether. I guess the rule in German is to pronounce a foreign word as in the language of origin. To me this is most noticeable with "Chance"; somehow I don't expect this very French sounding word to be used in German, especially when my American English pronunciation of it sounds so different.

Comment: Haha, yeah. "Chance" is an excellent example. The German version doesn't sound English nor French... we pronounce both vowels, and different than in either English or French.

Comment: @planetmaker: the "we" in in "we pronounce" is not as general as you may think as this is only the case in some parts of the German-speaking territory. I know of several areas where "Chance" is pronounced like it is in French. But then, words like "Étagère" and "Trottoir" are not common everywhere in Germany either.

Comment: @bakunin Du hast Recht. Die anderen Aussprachen habe ich auch schon gehört und es mag ein Bias meinerseits sein. https://www.dwds.de/wb/Chance?o=chance listet vier durchaus üblich und überraschend verschieden Versionen der Aussprache auf.